# Is there a compact formula for $x^n-(x-a)^{n-1}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm seeking a compact formula for the difference
$$ x^n-(x-a)^{n-1}$$
where $n \ge 1$ is an integer, and $x,a$ are numbers with $x > a > 0$.

Comment: That already looks pretty compact to me.  You could use the binomial theorem if you want to extract the coefficients.

Comment: Ha! I guess I mean __closed__ formula.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - I think most people would consider $x^n - (x-a)^{n-1}$ to be a closed formula.  Can you say what kind of expression you're looking for?

Comment: The sum of integer squares has the closed formula $$1^2+2^2 + \dots + a^2 = \frac{a(a+1)(2a+1)}{6}.$$ I guess I'm hoping for something like that, or at least something of the form $$\sum_j a_j f_n(x,a)$$ that isn't simply the binomial expansion formula.

Comment: It is pretty much accepted that a 'closed formula' is one NOT containing "..." at some point. Yours doesn't, so it is a closed formula.

Answer (score 2):

As users pointed out in the comments, $x^n-(x-a)^{n-1}$ itself is a closed as well as compact form. It is much better to work with than any other expanded form. One could expand the same via the binomial formula to write:
$$x^n-(x-a)^{n-1}=x^n-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (-1)^i{{n-1} \choose i}x^{n-1-i}a^i$$
which is clearly not useful. If you are asking whether the above expression can be factorized, it cannot. There is no 'better' way to express the difference. This might differ if there is some relation between $a$ and $x$, or if $a$ and $n$ were given constants.